# What to put on my CV while I'm waiting to hear thesis committee's decision?

Tags: thesis, cv, thesis-committee

I just handed in my Msc thesis, but it hasn't been accepted yet.  I expect it will be.  I've since started my PhD.

What should I put on my CV?

Comment: I'll put "Graduate student".

Comment: @scaaahu: I suggest you include your comment as an answer so you'd be getting up-votes in your answer instead.

Comment: You see "degree expected (date)" sometimes.

Answer (score 8):

List your dates as each type of student, with PhD student as your current position. For the MSc, I would put the date you submitted your thesis, so it's clear that you have finished doing the work, and something like 'awaiting outcome' to say that you haven't been awarded the MSc yet.

Having said that, I'm curious why you need a CV right now at all. The main thing is that you should not imply that you have the MSc already, particularly if that's likely to influence whether you get whatever you're applying for.